# Assigning results of getJson to array

Tags: knockout.js

What is the best way to assign the results of a getJson call to an array.   For instance, lets say one could hard code this:

```
 var users = [
 { id: 'Jack', name: 'Jack Smith' },
 { id: 'Jill', name: 'Jill Jones' },
 { id: 'Jane', name: 'Jane Chung' }
 ];
```

but I want to call the following service and and assign it to the the users array.

```
 function user(id, name) {
     var self = this;

     self.Id = id;
     self.Name = name;

 }


     $.getJSON("/api/users/", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                self.users.push(new user(val.id, val.name));
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery `$.map` function.

```
var ViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("/api/users/", function (data) {
        var mappedUsers = $.map(data, function(item) { return new User(item) });
        self.users(mappedUsers);
    });
};

function User(user) {
     var self = this;

     self.Id = user.id;
     self.Name = user.name;
 }
```

This is in the [knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) which I recommend going through.